# MongoDB: group by created_at and sender

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Message Collection Structure

```
Message = new Schema
    type:           String
    body:           Schema.Types.Mixed
    sender:         { type: String, enum: ['machine', 'profile'], default: 'machine' }
    created_at:     { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    updated_at:     { type: Date, default: Date.now }
```

Query

```
> db.messages.find({},{created_at: 1, sender: 1, _id: 0})
```

Returns

```
{ "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-20T08:31:59.890Z"), "sender" : "profile" }
{ "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-20T08:32:00.256Z"), "sender" : "machine" }
{ "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-20T08:32:24.908Z"), "sender" : "profile" }
{ "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-19T08:32:24.960Z"), "sender" : "machine" }
{ "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-19T08:33:36.456Z"), "sender" : "profile" }
{ "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-19T08:33:36.551Z"), "sender" : "machine" }
{ "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-19T08:50:19.331Z"), "sender" : "profile" }
{ "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-19T08:50:19.643Z"), "sender" : "machine" }
{ "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-19T08:50:29.638Z"), "sender" : "profile" }
{ "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-18T08:50:30.326Z"), "sender" : "machine" }
{ "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-18T08:50:40.996Z"), "sender" : "profile" }
{ "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-17T08:50:42.431Z"), "sender" : "machine" }
{ "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-17T08:50:48.606Z"), "sender" : "profile" }
{ "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-17T08:50:49.709Z"), "sender" : "machine" }
{ "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-17T08:50:51.163Z"), "sender" : "machine" }
{ "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-16T08:51:26.154Z"), "sender" : "profile" }
{ "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-16T08:51:26.186Z"), "sender" : "machine" }
{ "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-16T08:51:26.714Z"), "sender" : "machine" }
{ "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-15T08:53:36.383Z"), "sender" : "profile" }
{ "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-15T08:53:37.798Z"), "sender" : "machine" }
```

I need help with a query that will return responses grouped by date and sender.

For example: On date = 2016-08-15 AND sender = profile, count = 2

An array:

```
profile: [{ 2016-08-12: 10}, { 2016-08-13: 10} , { 2016-08-14: 5}]

machine: [{ 2016-08-12: 10}, { 2016-08-13: 10} , { 2016-08-14: 5}]
```

Need help with drafting it in a Mongo friendly format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would project `ISODate` to normal date string and then group on `date` and `sender`

Query will look like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  // Normalize ISODate and remove time part.
  {$project:
    {created_at:
      {
        $dateToString:
        {format:"%Y-%m-%d", date:"$created_at"}
      }, 
      sender:1
    }
  },
  // Group documents by created_at, sender and calculate number of documents.
  {$group:
    {_id:
      {created_at:"$created_at", sender:"$sender"}, 
      count:{$sum: 1}
    }
  },
  // Sort result by created_at desc
  {$sort:
    {"_id.created_at":-1}
  },
  // Optional: $project to make result look pretty.
  {$project:
    {_id:0, created_at:"$_id.created_at", sender:"$_id.sender", count:1}
  }
])
```

> Note: Last `$project` stage is optional.

Out will be something like: (I'm skipping full result for brevity.

```
{ 
    "count" : NumberInt(1), 
    "created_at" : "2016-08-20", 
    "sender" : "machine"
}
{ 
    "count" : NumberInt(2), 
    "created_at" : "2016-08-20", 
    "sender" : "profile"
}
{ 
    "count" : NumberInt(3), 
    "created_at" : "2016-08-19", 
    "sender" : "profile"
}
{ 
    "count" : NumberInt(3), 
    "created_at" : "2016-08-19", 
    "sender" : "machine"
}
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2):

You should [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) on `created_at` and `sender` first, taking the count of each bucket. Then group on `sender`, and [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) the dates with counts into an array.

```
[
  {$group: {
      _id: {
          date: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$created_at" } },
          sender: '$sender'
      },
      count: {$sum: 1}
  }},
  {$group: {
      _id: '$_id.sender',
      arr: {$push: {date: '$_id.date', count: '$count'}}
  }}
]
```